# Reader closed error during Parallel ForEach handling automapper

Tags: c#, multithreading, automapper, parallel.foreach, telerik-open-access

I get data from a database by using telerik openaccess ORM.
I store these in a list by using `ToList()` method.

Then I use a `Parallel.ForEach` to map the model objects to DTO objects by using AutoMapper.

An error occurs in the `Parallel.ForEach` after the first or second treatment in the loop:

```
DataStoreException: System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid attempt to call IsDBNull when reader is closed.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.CheckHeaderIsReady(Int32 columnIndex, Boolean permitAsync, String methodName)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.IsDBNull(Int32 i)
   at OpenAccessRuntime.Data.IntConverter.Read(DataHolder& data)
   at OpenAccessRuntime.Relational.RelationalGenericOID.CopyKeyFields(DataHolder& data)
   at OpenAccessRuntime.Relational.fetch.FopGetOID.fetch(FetchResult fetchResult, StateContainer stateContainer)
   at OpenAccessRuntime.Relational.fetch.FetchSpec.createRow(FetchResult fetchResult, StateContainer stateContainer)
```

I can admit the connection is not thread safe but why to need this connection yet after using the `ToList()` method ? All data are supposed to be retrieved after using this method.

Does it exist another way to do it ?

My code:

```
IEnumerable<Person> persons = database.GetData<Person>().ToList();

var safeList = new ConcurrentBag<PersonDTO>();
Parallel.ForEach(persons, (p) =>
{
    var dto = Mapper.Map<PersonDTO>(p);
    safeList.Add(dto);
});

return safeList.ToList();
```

Comment: I would guess either you're not loading them all beforehand or some of the properties in `Person` are lazy loaded. As an aside, I can't imagine your mapping is terribly expensive - I'd be surprised if this gives you any noticeable benefit in performance.

Comment: Where are you calling `.ToList();`? You're not calling it before the parallel mapping, so I'd expect you still have an `IQueryable` at that point.

Comment: @CharlesMager: In Person class, there is different properties as IList<>, ... The mapping takes about 6 seconds.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar: You are right, error while copy-paste. I just edited that.

Comment: Could you include the `Person` class in the question? Does it contain any properties of type `IQueryable`?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: I used the `Person` class for example but my class owns a great property hierarchy. Does the ORM get data until a given level in the hierarchy with the method `ToList()` for performance reasons ? All properties and sub-properties are of type: IList<>, IEnumerable<>, Stack<> or basic types as float, int, bool, ...

Comment: If mapping takes 6 seconds, I'd suspect that various properties are loaded lazily and nearly all of that time is taken in database queries. A quick google suggests this is the default behaviour for OpenAccess. This would explain your exception. I wouldn't expect mapping data in memory to take in the order of seconds.

Comment: @CharlesMager: I think so too. But I'm surprised the `ToList()` method didn't solve my issue given the type of properties. I don't have any `Lazy<>` properties.

Comment: Try to avoid having `IEnumerable<T>` properties, unless it's your intention that these properties should be lazy/deferred. Convert them to arrays or lists, and see if the problem persists.

Comment: I doubt they'd be of type `Lazy<T>`. You'd be best reading the documentation to work out how it works and how you could eagerly load properties instead. I can't find any docs, any links redirect to [this page](https://www.telerik.com/data-access-sunsetting) stating that the product was discontinued in 2015 and suggesting you use Entity Framework instead.